# Do I need to declare host_permissions in my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm creating a chrome extension that should be able to be accessed by the user on any website they are on. I don't have any content scripts, only popup.js and background.js. Would I need to have my host permissions in manifest V3 like this? Or am I able to omit the host_permissions?

`"host_permissions": [ "*://*/*" ]`

Comment: It depends on what your extension does.

Comment: @wOxxOm it is pretty much a study timer extension, that allows users to see the countdown timer based on how much time they have left in their study session. At the end of the timer, a notification is sent.

Comment: Then you don't need host_permissions. Those are only required if you want to inject something in a matching page, download from a matching URL, or observe via webRequest and similar API.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to add host permission unless your extension needs to interact directly with the users browser/client data, for example cookies, webRequest, and tabs.

this article helps:
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/host_permissions#:~:text=Use%20the%20host_permissions%20key%20to,a%20request%20for%20a%20permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/host_permissions#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20host_permissions%20key%20to,a%20request%20for%20a%20permission).